# Are DynamoDB conditional writes strongly consistent?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Suppose that a given table already contains the following key value pair:

"abc" => { i: 1, v: "foo" }

Then, two clients issue conflicting concurrent conditional writes. Client 1 writes:

"abc" => { i: 2, v: "bar1" } if i == 1

Client 2 writes:

"abc" => { i: 2, v: "bar2" } if i == 1

Then, is it guaranteed that at most one client's write operation will succeed?

Comment: The answer is too short even for a comment: Yes. I mean, that is their whole point.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to be 100% certain.

Comment: The answer may be short, but cheers from 2018. Sometimes the most concise answers are the best.

Comment: If both requests come at the same time, how does DynamoDB determine which record it'll retain? `bar1` or `bar2`?

Comment: @Joseph did you get a reply for this ? thanks

Comment: @dDarkLORD nope. But I assume whichever record makes it first to DDB

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly the use case they're designed for. You can see an example in the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalUpdate).