# How to guarantee a business rule in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a business rule that one account can only have 3 projects at any given time.

In order to keep it efficient, we track the number of projects in an "userData" field instead of doing a COUNT query

Consider the following example objects already in DynamoDB:

```
userData : { createdProjects : 2 }
project1 : { id : 1 }
project2 : { id : 2 }
```

In order to enforce this rule, we've done the following when creating a project (pseudo code)

```
in transaction:
  putItem(key = "project3", object = { id : 3 })
  updateItem(
    key = "userData", 
    expression = "createdProjects = createdProjects + 1"
    condition = "createdProjects < 3"
  )
```

Now, if the user tries to create a project at the same time with two computers let's say, will DynamoDB guarantee that he won't be able to create more than 3?

I know there are similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27198804/are-dynamodb-conditional-writes-strongly-consistent), but I wanted to know if this also works in a transaction, because my condition is in another object.

Also, is my pseudo code the best approach? open to other ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a transaction for this.
Just include the `PutItem` request and `UpdateItem` request with the condition in a transaction and either both will complete or none of them.

Transactions are the way to provide this all or nothing behavior.

> With the transaction write API, you can group multiple `Put`, `Update`, `Delete`, and `ConditionCheck` actions. You can then submit the actions as a single `TransactWriteItems` operation that either succeeds or fails as a unit. The same is true for multiple Get actions, which you can group and submit as a single `TransactGetItems` operation.
>
> — [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transactions.html)